# Android camera setOrientation not affected

Tags: android, android-camera

I write my own app of camera and have issue with output image.
When i tring to make a picture i set orientation degree using next code:

```
mCamera.getParameters().set("rotation", mOrientation);
```

or

```
mCamera.getParameters().setRotation(mOrientation);
```

or

```
mCamera.getParameters().setRotation(0);
```

all of these snippets doesn't rotate output image

Answer (score 1):

try using like this

```
 if (camInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                displayRotation = (cameraRotationOffset + degrees) % 360;
                displayRotation = (360 - displayRotation) % 360; // compensate
                // the
                // mirror
            } else { // back-facing
                displayRotation = (cameraRotationOffset - degrees + 360) % 360;
            }
 cam.setDisplayOrientation(displayRotation);
```

replace degree with your angle

Answer (score 0):

You are missing setParameters, that's why I like spliting
Usually I use:

`Camera.Parameters parameters=mcamera.getParameters();
parameters.setRotation(90); //use 90, 180, 270
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);`

Though making shortcut of it, I am not sure if it works, so I suggest upper method

```
mCamera.setParameters(mCamera.getParameters.setRotation(90));
```